# How i can merge Microsoft Word table cells horizontally using OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, merge, ms-word, cell, openxml

I have a table in Microsoft Word.
I need to merge two cells in a row of a table.
I get the cells I need:

```
Wordprocessing.TableRow row = table.Elements<Wordprocessing.TableRow>().ElementAt(i);

 Wordprocessing.TableCell cell1 = row.Elements<Wordprocessing.TableCell>().ElementAt(j);

 Wordprocessing.TableCell cell2 = row.Elements<Wordprocessing.TableCell>().ElementAt(j+1);
```

How I can merge these cells horizontally?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to append a `HorizontalMerge` object to the cell's `TableProperties`.

```
TableCellProperties cellOneProperties = new TableCellProperties();
cellOneProperties.Append(new HorizontalMerge()
{
    Val = MergedCellValues.Restart
});

TableCellProperties cellTwoProperties = new TableCellProperties();
cellTwoProperties.Append(new HorizontalMerge()
{
    Val = MergedCellValues.Continue
});

cell1.Append(cellOneProperties);
cell2.Append(cellTwoProperties);
```